# Terminating proc_open after x Seconds

Tags: php, process, exec, pdftk, proc-open

I am using pdftk to merge pdf files. Occasionaly a user uploads a ill formed pdf and it hangs the process returning no errors and consuming all the server resources. To prevent this i am looking at implementing the process call through `proc_open` and wish to set a time limit for the process to run and terminate the process if it exceeds the time limit.

Below is an example of the function that I am using to merge the pdf files if I set

`stream_set_blocking($process, 0);`

it returns an error:

`stream_set_blocking(): supplied resource is not a valid stream resource`

I presume something in this function is malformed and hope someone will be able to point me in the right direction... The function currently isn't returning any errors however does not terminate after 30 seconds as required

```
 protected function pdf_merge($documents,$output_file,$time = 30){      

        $end = time() + $time;
        $cmd = sprintf('/usr/local/bin/pdftk %s cat output %s', $documents, $output_file);

        $descriptorspec = array(
           0 => array("pipe", "r"),  
           1 => array("pipe", "w"),  
           2 => array("file","./error.log","a")
        );

        $process = proc_open($cmd, $descriptorspec, $pipes);

        if (is_resource($process)) {
            stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], 0);
            while (!feof($pipes[1]) && (time() < $end)) {

                fwrite($pipes[0], stream_get_contents($pipes[0]));
                fclose($pipes[0]);

                $pdf_content = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
                fclose($pipes[1]);

                $return_value = proc_close($process);

                return $return_value;
            }   
            error_log('file is taking too long... kill process');
            proc_terminate();               
        }
    }
```

Comment: `max_execution_time` in php.ini? http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time

Comment: `stream_set_blocking()` does not work with pipes opened with `proc_open()` (see https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47918)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm off base here, does most of this code run?

```
fwrite($pipes[0], stream_get_contents($pipes[0]));
```

Looks like you are trying to write to the pipe whatever you can read from the pipe...

Also, you may want to check with get_proc_status() as the command may have completed by the time you try to set the blocking...